# Integral Measures: Variation

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Given a measure $\lambda\geq0$.

Regard a real function $h:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with $h\in\mathcal{L}$.

Consider the real measure $\mu(E):=\int_E h\mathrm{d}\lambda$.

> Then its total variation measure is given by: $|\mu|(E)=\int_E|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda$

How to prove this rigorously?

Especially, this implies for positive and negative part:
$$\mu_\pm(E)=\frac12(|\mu|(E)\pm\mu(E))=\int_E\frac12(|h|\pm h)\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_Eh_\pm\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

Note that this thread is a lemma for: [Complex Measures: Variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950627/79762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Oops, got it meanwhile...*

Split the space into:
$$\Omega_\pm:=\{h\gtrless 0\}$$

Then for any measurable set one has:
$$|\mu|(E)=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\left|\int_Ah\mathrm{d}\lambda\right|=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\left|\int_{A\cap\Omega_+}h\mathrm{d}\lambda\right|+\left|\int_{A\cap\Omega_-}h\mathrm{d}\lambda\right|=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\int_{A\cap\Omega_+}|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda+\int_{A\cap\Omega_-}|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}\sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\int_A|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda=\sup_{E=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}\int_E|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_E|h|\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hahn decomposition theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) and notice that defining $P:=\{h>0\}$ and $N:=\{h\leqslant 0\}$, we get the wanted conclusion.